# Strange Issue with Text Field Only Returning 1 letter or NULL

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am running a beta test on my app and one user using an iphone 4s is having an issue where after typing a query into his search box, the query ran returns 'null' every time, unless he simply types the letter 'a'. I should note that this works just fine on the rest of the devices I have tested: the simulator and an iphone 5 and an iphone 5s.

Here is the relevant code:

In First ViewController.m

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"search_segue"]) {
    SearchController* searchController = [segue destinationViewController];
    searchController.query = self.searchQuery.text;
}
}
```

In Second ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"%@", _query);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out as a guess:

I had the vars set as:

```
(weak, nonatomic)
```

And changed them to:

```
(strong, nonatomic)
```

And that fixed it.